# SQL Query for three tables with calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was given an interview question and I cannot resolve it. I'm not in the SQL field, and it was more to show problem solving ability than SQL ability. I'd still like to figure it out though!

It was in MS SQL server, but a generic SQL answer is acceptable.

I have 3 tables: Sales, Customers, Products and NO NULL values in the tables.

**Customers**: Customer_ID, Customer_Name

**Products**: Product_ID, Product_Price

**Sales**: Customer_ID, Product_ID, Number_Purchased

They want me to display, the client who has paid the most, to the client who has paid the least.

So I need to link the Customer ID from Customers to the Customer ID in Sales and then the sales to the product price and work out Price * Number Purchased and assign it to the correct person.

I tried something like this at the time: (obviously wrong)

```
SELECT Customers.Customer_ID, Customers.Customer_Name, SUM(Sales.Number_Purchased *Products.Product_Price) as Total
FROM (Customers 
INNER JOIN Products 
ON Customers.Customer_ID = Products.Customer_ID)
INNER JOIN Sales ON 
Products.Product_ID = Sales.Product_ID
GROUP BY Customers.Customer_ID, Customers.Customer_Name
```

Obviously I'm not good with SQL but if somone can give me a shove in the right direction to solving this (second Interview is in a few hours!) I would really appreciate it! I've gotten myself tied in knots.

Comment: I understand these customers sell things to each other. So there should be another table or another field for defining which product belongs to which customer. Sometimes they look for questions instead of answers.

Comment: Sorry, I should assume the company are making the sales. Each customer buys different products from the one company. They do not sell to each other. I think my rubbish code may be causing the confusion. This is the company database. They want to know which customer of theirs spent the most money!  However, I will ask that question today in the second interview as it is a clever one, and they may be trying to throw me off!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the list sorted from paid the most to paid the least, add:

```
ORDER BY SUM(Sales.Number_Purchased * Products.Product_Price) DESC
```

Additionally, you have to change some of the JOIN conditions, since you are not establishing the correct connection between the tables.

And since you are doing this in MS-ACCESS, you have to wrap the JOINS with parenthesis

It should be:

```
SELECT Customers.Customer_ID, 
       Customers.Customer_Name,
       SUM(Sales.Number_Purchased * Products.Product_Price) AS Total
FROM ((Customers 
INNER JOIN Sales ON Sales.Customer_ID = Customers.Customer_ID)
INNER JOIN Products ON Sales.Product_ID = Products.Product_ID)
GROUP BY Customers.Customer_ID, Customers.Customer_Name
ORDER BY SUM(Sales.Number_Purchased * Products.Product_Price) DESC
```

Comment: It is giving me a syntax error missing operator, however I may have named things wrong. I will investigate now.

Comment: @RossC. I see the error. it was in the JOINs. you were joining in the wrong columns. Try now

Comment: I am testing in Access so that may be the issue. I still get Syntax Error, missing operator on the first Inner Join. All the solutions below are giving error.

Comment: In access you have to have parenthesis around the joins. I edited my answer

Comment: That is perfect, many thanks. The difference beteween MySQL, SQL Sever and Access is bewildering to me at the moment. Many thanks!

Comment: This is standard SQL. it would work in every DBMS, but access has that little trickery of the parenthesis :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd prefer to approach this question in the following steps.

First of all, find out the total of each purchase done by all the customers.

```
SELECT Customer_ID, SUM (Sales.Number_Purchased * Products.Product_Price)
FROM Sales
INNER JOIN Products ON Products.Product_ID = Sales.Product_ID
GROUP BY Customer_ID
```

Then we would like to know the customer name. So we will inner join the Customes table.

```
SELECT Customer_ID, Customer_Name, SUM (Sales.Number_Purchased * Products.Product_Price)
FROM Sales
INNER JOIN Products ON Products.Product_ID = Sales.Product_ID
INNER JOIN Customers ON Customers.Customer_ID = Sales.Customer_ID
GROUP BY Customer_ID
```

Finally, you can do a ORDER BY statement to find out the ones who paid the most and the least.

Take note that in your code, Products.Customer_ID is *not* allowed because Customer_ID is not one of the columns in the Products table.

**EDIT**
Oops, there is an ambiguous column in my second SQL. It should be "SELECT Customers.Customer_ID" because the column name Customer_ID is used in two different tables.

Comment: Excellent idea to break it down. They *may* want one query, but this does help learn the concepts, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Boy have I been in your shoes, half the time not allowed to normalize tables in a DB :(

Any who i've quickly looked so forgive the syntax errors. but you will get the idea:

```
SELECT Customers.Customer_ID, 
    Customers.Customer_Name, 
    SUM(Sales.Number_Purchased *Products.Product_Price) as Total
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN SALES
ON customers.customer_ID = Sales.Customer_ID
left JOIN Products
ON  Sales.productid = products.product_ID
Customers.Customer_ID, Customers.Customer_Name
GROUP BY Customers.Customer_ID, Customers.Customer_Name
ORDER BY SUM(Sales.Number_Purchased * Products.Product_Price) DESC
```

Cant check it but basically you were right but not on joins.

Inner join will only get matching results. But what about users who haven't brought anything?  They wont exist in the sales part so they wont exist in your results, which in the job i was in was a bad thing as they want see all customers.
This allows you to pull back all of them, and then if you need to, filter out the null sales. 
Usually its best to zero value them, you can then provide information on customers who haven't spent. (added info makes them happy ;) )

SO, use a left join, you will get every customer regardless of spend.
match that up then to the products remember you want to keep all sales, and making sure there isnt a problem with missing data, use another left.
then really just use an order by, and done.

hope this helps

Comment: I thought Inner as they said not to worry about NULL values, but still that would be more correct!

Comment: This will not fulfil the requirement as stated as: They want me to display, the client who has paid the most, to the client who has paid the least.

Comment: @KMB oh? why not? is there something i missed?

Comment: and this will provide him confirmed data, including customers without sales. customer with null sales are considered 0 sales usually and thus should be including as it also gives added information, so i fail to see why this wont give him everything? plus more?
forgive syntax errors not really in a position to check, if thats what your getting at

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you missed.
A) Links between tables are incorrect. Following the key columns is useful exercise
B) As Filipe pointed out the ORDER BY clause does the sorting

```
SELECT 
  Customers.Customer_ID, Customers.Customer_Name, 
  SUM(Sales.Number_Purchased *Products.Product_Price) as Total
FROM Customers 
  -- connect sales to customers
  INNER JOIN Sales ON 
    ON Sales.Customer_ID = Customers.Customer_ID
  -- connect products to sales
 INNER JOIN Products 
   Products.Product_ID = Sales.Product_ID
-- group to deliver an aggregate
GROUP BY Customers.Customer_ID, Customers.Customer_Name
-- sort
ORDER BY SUM(Sales.Number_Purchased * Products.Product_Price) DESC
```